# how to search for key value in php multidimentional and return array with only search values

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [program] => 615
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 572
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Moorestown
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [program] => 313
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 267
                            [campus_title_override] => Colorado - Denver
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 269
                            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - East Windsor
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 277
                            [campus_title_override] => Illinois - Melrose Park (Chicago Area)
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 279
                            [campus_title_override] => Indiana - Indianapolis
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 281
                            [campus_title_override] => Maryland - Columbia
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 570
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey  - Mahwah (Bergen County/NY Metro Area)
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 580
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Union
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 576
                            [campus_title_override] => New York - Queens
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 574
                            [campus_title_override] => Pennsylvania - Philadelphia
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 560
                            [campus_title_override] => Tennessee - Nashville
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 557
                            [campus_title_override] => Texas - Grand Prairie (Dallas/Fort Worth Metroplex)
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [program] => 617
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 269
                            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - East Windsor
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 279
                            [campus_title_override] => Indiana - Indianapolis
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 570
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey  - Mahwah (Bergen County/NY Metro Area)
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 557
                            [campus_title_override] => Texas - Grand Prairie (Dallas/Fort Worth Metroplex)
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [program] => 582
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 267
                            [campus_title_override] => Colorado - Denver
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 269
                            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - East Windsor
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 277
                            [campus_title_override] => Illinois - Melrose Park (Chicago Area)
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 279
                            [campus_title_override] => Indiana - Indianapolis
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 560
                            [campus_title_override] => Tennessee - Nashville
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 557
                            [campus_title_override] => Texas - Grand Prairie
                        )

                )

        )
```

in the `campus_title_override` key if the value matches "New Jersey" I want to return the array result matching new jersey array key. In the current array, in the `array 0, 1, and 2` it has the value `"New Jersey"` in the `campus_title_override` key. I want to only return array `ids 0,1 and 2`. Whatever matches the key value to "New Jersey" I want to return the main array result set.

I have tried the following example from stackoverflow

```
function search($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array)) {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
            $results[] = $array;
        }

        foreach ($array as $subarray) {
            $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
        }
    }

    return $results;
}


print_r(search($array, 'campus_title_override', 'New Jersey'));
```

and it returns empty result set.

I also have question on how I'd do the same on this array set:

```
       Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 269
            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - East Windsor
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 313
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 582
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 617
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 584
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 619
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 621
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 625
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 271
            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - New Britain
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 619
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 621
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 599
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 607
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 273
            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - Shelton
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 619
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 599
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 607
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 609
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 283
            [campus_title_override] => Massachusetts - Somerville (Boston Area)
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 595
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 599
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 605
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 564
            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Iselin (Formerly located in Edison, NJ)
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 611
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 599
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 607
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [campus] => 570
            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Mahwah (Bergen County/NY Metro Area)
            [programs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 313
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 617
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 619
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [program] => 621
                            [program_title_override] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code? Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 `foreach` (1 for elements, 1 for the campuses) and `strpos()` to search if the value of `campus_title_override` contains the value of the search.

```
$array = array(/*your data*/); 
$search = "New Jersey";
$out = [];
// for each element in the array,
foreach ($array as $index => $item) {
  // for each campuses,
  foreach ($item['campuses'] as $campus) {
    // if 'campus_title_override' contains search,
    if (strpos($campus['campus_title_override'], $search) !== false) {
      $out[] = $item ;
      break; // no need to continue, we got the item.
    }
  }
}
print_r($out);
```

Outputs: (https://3v4l.org/YRCma)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [program] => 615
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 572
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Moorestown
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [program] => 313
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 267
                            [campus_title_override] => Colorado - Denver
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 269
                            [campus_title_override] => Connecticut - East Windsor
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 277
                            [campus_title_override] => Illinois - Melrose Park (Chicago Area)
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 279
                            [campus_title_override] => Indiana - Indianapolis
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 281
                            [campus_title_override] => Maryland - Columbia
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 570
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey  - Mahwah (Bergen County/NY Metro Area)
                        )
```

Comment: How can I return the whole result set that matches the array?

Comment: @unixmiah You want to get the "campus" or the `$item`?

Comment: for instance in the first array result set if it matches New Jersey in the array campus_title_override I want to return the result set of that array like this Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [program] => 615
            [program_title_override] => 
            [campuses] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [campus] => 572
                            [campus_title_override] => New Jersey - Moorestown
                        )

                )

        )

Comment: so instead of returning 0,1,2 I want to return that array result set

Comment: i would like to return the array results that matches the New Jersey in the campus_title_override

Comment: that looks perfect, thank you. let me give it a try.

Comment: Also, please see https://3v4l.org/H3Pum (removes campuses that not match)

Comment: i have added another array I need to do the same (I have updated the question), I have applied the code but not seeing the same result as the other array set.

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop trough the array using a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

For every element loop trough it's `campuses` property and check if the conditions you want are found.

If the conditions are met, insert the main id into an array and break the 2nd for loop.

**Example:**

```
$ids = [];

$array = [
    [
        'campuses' => [
            [
                'campus_title_override' => 'a'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach ($array as $id => $obj)
{
    foreach ($obj['campuses'] as $campus)
    {
        if ($campus['campus_title_override'] == 'a')
        {
            array_push($ids, $id);
            break;
        }
    }
}

var_dump($ids);
```

You can learn more about Multi Demensional Arrays [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Please read the articles to learn about what this code does, and don't just copy it ;)

Answer (score 1):

For array with a depth level 2 i.e.

```
array(
[0]   =>  array(
               [key]   => 'value'
          )
)
```

You can use array_search but it will not work for your array. To search you will have to manually search using foreach loop.

```
$mainArray = array(
        'compression' => array('7z', 'cbr', 'deb', 'gz', 'pkg', 'rar', 'rpm', 'sitx', 'tar.gz', 'zip', 'zipx'),
        'scripts' => array('php', 'js', 'css', 'asp', 'aspx', 'htm', 'html', 'cc', 'cpp', 'py', 'jsp'),
        'documentType' => array('txt', 'doc', 'docx', 'log', 'rtf'),
    );
    foreach($mainArray as $key=>$value){
        if (in_array(strtolower('php'), $value)){ // Return only if found during the loop
           return $key;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.